# Pass data from kotlin activity to java DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

Need help i have been trying to find a way so that i can pass data from kotlin to newInstance of a DialogFragment.
kotlin code below

```
private var messageDialog: MessageDialog? = null

override fun onLoginFail(value: String?) {
    //TODO:find hpw to implement this
    messageDialog = MessageDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.sign_title),getString(R.string.signin_msg,value)
    messageDialog?.show(supportFragmentManager,null)
}
```

DialogFragment Below

```
public static MessageDialog newInstance(String title, String msg){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(EXTRA_MSG,msg);
    args.putString(EXTRA_TITLE,title);
    MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog();
    messageDialog.setArguments(args);
    return messageDialog;
}
```

Comment: You are putting values in budle in DialogFragment. But according to question you want to pass data from activity. ?

Comment: yes i want to pass

Comment: Then recheck your code. I think you shoud pass the bundle from activity not from dialog.

Comment: yes but how do i pass data from kotlin to newInstance of a java DialogFragment?

Comment: What are you getting? I mean any exception or warning?

Comment: i'm not getting anything cz i don't know how to pass data between them

Comment: see this https://medium.com/@azjkjensen/using-the-newinstance-pattern-in-kotlin-e40c1b4ba1ef

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin for making static methods we use companion objects, here is what you can do in your case:

In **Message Dialog:**

```
 companion object {
    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment Message Dialog Fragment.
     */
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(title: String, msg: String) = MessageDialog().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString(EXTRA_TITLE, tile) 
            putString(EXTRA_MSG, msg)
        }
    }
}
```

In **Message Dialog Fragment** `onCreate` method:

```
var title =""
var msg = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    arguments?.let {
        title= it.getString(EXTRA_TITLE)
        msg = it.getString(EXTRA_MSG)
    }

}
```

Now you can call `MessageDialog.newInstance("Sample title","Sample msg")`

Comment: Yes, you would be able to pass data like this. Call `newInstance()` method from your kotlin class and pass the data in arguments. Put first code block inside Dialog fragment, and second code block in your DialogFragment's `onCreate` method

Comment: go through the code i have shared i have already implemented newInstance but by using java.

Comment: what error are you facing? usually java code do not create problem when called from kotlin class.

Comment: I think you have already come halfway, you just need to `getArguments` in you fragment `onCreate` method, my `onCreate` code is Kotlin but it is doing the same thing.